# C debugging in vscode stops at some printf. How do I fix it?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have been trying to debug this simple C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int fahr, celsius;
    int inf, sup, incr;
    inf = 0;
    sup = 300;
    incr = 20;
    celsius = inf;
    while (celsius <= sup){
        printf("%d\t%d\n", celsius, fahr);
        celsius = celsius + incr;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it works well, but when I try to debug it, it shows the message `Could not load source './stdio-common/./stdio-common/printf.c': 'SourceRequest' not supported..` and the code simply doesn't run, it just stops and I can't step into it.
I've tried to make changes to my json file as others who had the same problem did(https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3831), but it's still giving me the same result.

Here's my json configs after I tried to do as stated in the link:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
      "args": [
        "compile as g++ -g file.cpp -o file.o"
        
      ],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        
      ]
      
    },
    
    {
      "sourceFileMap": { "./../../src/": "~/pemCode/angle/src/" },
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": false,
      "cwd": "/home/fabio/Documents",
      "program": "/home/fabio/Documents/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You don't need a debugger until the compiler delivers correct code: it tells you that `fahr` is not assigned any value.

Comment: The library needs to be a debug build before you can step into it, with the source code available.

Comment: @WeatherVane fixed it, same issue. added the line 'fahr = celsius * 9/5 + 32;' to the code. still the same thing

Comment: How do I set it up as  a debug build?

Comment: Most libraries don't provide the source or a debug version. Why do you need to debug the libary functions?

Comment: I don't want to debug the library functions. I want to debug the code, like, doing it step by step the whole running process. But it stops at printf, that's my problem.

Comment: There are two important debugger commands, "step into" and "step over". You should step into functions you want to debug. You should step over functions you do not want to debug. `printf` is not your code, so step over it.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI can't step over it as well. It just stops at the printf command

Comment: There are many ways to completely ruin a vscode configuration. Maybe there are ways that have the effect that you describe, but I'm not familiar with any. Try to set vscode aside and run gdb from the console. Are you able to debug this way?

Comment: Yes, I tested it in the console and it works perfectly

Comment: So that's a vscode bug. Why do people punish themselves with vscode? There are many working IDEs out there.

Comment: You should prefer to initialize variables `int incr = 20; int inf=0; int sup = 300;`.   Once you do that it's pretty clear that `fahr` is not initialized.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior.

Comment: Prefer `for` to `while` loops, i.e. `for(int celsius = inf; celsius <= sup; celsius += incr) printf("%d\t%d\n", celsius, fahr);`

Comment: Prefer symbolic or const variables if they don't change.  In your case `incr` and `sup` are constants.

Comment: You should tag this vscode as you are asking about how to use your ide and not what is wrong with your program.